# Sorting a Dataset by an enumerated column with assigned values

Tags: dataset, sorting

A $\mathtt{Dataset}$ has a column $C$ with enumerated values $c_i$, to each of which a number $n_{c_i}$ is manually assigned. The $\mathtt{Dataset}$ needs to be sorted based on the numbers.

---

**MWE**: Suggest there's a $\mathtt{Dataset}$:

```
ds = Dataset[
  AssociationThread[{"ID", "Food"}, 
     StringSplit[#, ","]] & /@ {"1,Apple", "2,Banana", "3,Banana", 
    "4,Cherry", "5,Apple"}]
```

The column "Food" of any record will be one of "Apple", "Banana", and "Cherry".

Now, for some reason, One’d like to sort the records by Column "Food", assigning 2 to "Apple", 1 to "Banana", and 3 to "Cherry" (maybe 0 to anything else). The result $\mathtt{Dataset}$ will thus have Column "ID" as $\mathtt{\{2, 3, 1, 5, 4\}}$:

```
expectedDs = 
 Dataset[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Food"}, 
     StringSplit[#, ","]] & /@ {"1,Apple", "2,Banana", "3,Banana", 
     "4,Cherry", "5,Apple"}[[{2, 3, 1, 5, 4}]]]
```

Comment: `f[“Apple”] = 2; f[“Banana”] = 1; f[“Cherry”] = 3; dat[SortBy[Key[“Food”] /* f]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[sort]
sort = AssociationThread[{"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"}, {2, 1, 3}]; 

ds[SortBy[sort @ #Food &]]
```

[image]